# How to convert Scala collection Seq[(Int, Seq[String])] to Java collection List[(int, List[String])]?

Tags: java, scala

I know that there are two extremely useful objects in scala.collection package, which will help us to achieve this goal:

- JavaConverters (If I want to be explicit and tell exactly what I want to convert)
- JavaConversions (If I don’t want co control conversions and let
  compiler make implicit work for me)

but I have some troubles to apply them in my case because my data structure is a little bit more complex than the other ones that I saw in many examples.

I'm in scala code and I want that my scala function return a Java collection. So I wanto to convert Scala Seq[(Int, Seq[String])] to Java collection List[(int, List[String])].

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use map to at first map `Seq[(Int, Seq[String])]` to `Seq[(Int, List[String])]` and then use again the same function to main collection

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions
val seq : Seq[(Int, Seq[String])] = some code
val seqOfLists = seq.map(s => (s._1, JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(s._2)))
val listOfLists = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(seqOfLists)
```

Or newer API:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val seq : Seq[(Int, Seq[String])] = some code
val seqOfLists = seq.map(s => (s._1, s._2.asJava))
val listOfLists = seqOfLists.asJava
```

Comment: @AlexSavitsky Ok I added newer API. I didn't notice deprecation, nice catch

Comment: @AlexSavitsky BTW, Thanks for information why you downvoted - that caused that I had possibility to change the question and also learn something. That is very community-friendly way of improvements in answers ;)

Comment: Upvoted it back. This is a great example of positive collaboration.

Comment: @AlexSavitsky Exactly :) Thank you :)

Comment: @TGaweda Thank you so much, It works! But I need of a little bit help again... I have some troubles when I receive the converted data structure in Java code... How can manage the list that I receive? If I use: List receivedList = OggettoScala.getDirectedGraphCommunityDetection(neo); System.out.println(list.get(0)); I can see: (0,[pablo, luca]) So, How can I obtain 0 or [pablo, luca] separately?

Comment: @Fobi Use for first element `list.get(0)._1()` or for the second: `list.get(0)._2()`

Comment: @TGaweda I'm using Java code now... I can't use this notation: List receivedList = OggettoScala.getDirectedGraphCommunityDetection(neo); System.out.println(receivedList.get(0)._1);

Comment: @Fobi note `()` - it's a normal Java function

Comment: @TGaweda Sorry... but Eclipse gives me an error: "method _1() is undefined fo type Object"

Comment: @Fobi Make sure your functions' signature is `List[(Int, List[String])]`. It seems that you are loosing types

Comment: @TGaweda Yes... my Scala function signature is: java.util.List[(Int, java.util.List[String])] I think that I need to parameterized the List type with something like List<>... but how exactly?

Comment: @Fobi Full signature is `List<Tuple2<Int, List<String>>>`

Answer (score 3):

[`JavaConversions`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html) is deprecated since Scala 2.12.0. Use [`JavaConverters`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) instead:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val seq: Seq[(Int, Seq[String])] = ???
val javaList = seq.map(x => (x._1, x._2.asJava)).asJava
// java.util.List[(Int, java.util.List[String])]
```